# File manager keeps opening in loop

Tags: gnome, xorg, filemanager, mate

I am using Gnome with Mate. For some reason I have file manager constantly opening in a loop, so that I have 4-5 "Starting File Manager" items in my task bar. Does anyone know how to stop this or where to look that may shed light on the phenomena.

I have looked at programs running and there is a *wnck-applet*, which I have not observed before. When I kill it, it shuts down gnome, which then starts up again.

Comment: to close the file manager try `killall nautilus`. dose  other file manager have the same issue. If u have no other file manager try installing thunar

Comment: nautilus is not running.

Comment: are you using some other file manager as default?

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to go to *System Monitor* and *kill* Caja. I imagine this can be done from the terminal with:

killall caja

Answer (score 1):

Just encountered the very same behavior on Linux Mint 17.3 with MATE:

The `mate-panel` on login was opening infinite caja instances in loop, endlessly, and nothing helps to stop that.
`top` and `htop` commands have shown the 30% CPU is taken by `wnck-applet` at `/usr/lib/mate-panel/wnck-applet`.

As I recalled that previous shutdown was made abruptly, so the guess was, proved to be true, that this new behavior is caused by some file loss or non-finished write operation:

caja starting command line is:

```
caja --sm-client-id <long-string-of-digits> --sm-client-state-file /home/$USER/.config/session-state/caja-1525086690.desktop
```

The directory `/home/$USER/.config/session-state/` contains current state of desktop session, this info used also for session program restarts on every new login in MATE or other.

As it turns out this `caja-1525086690.desktop` file was not well written, and its settings line `documents=` contains corrupted XML data, with absent `</xml>` tag, i.e. not closed `<xml>` tag:

```
[Caja]
documents=<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n<session>\n  <history>\n    <bookmark name="..."...
```

with last line of.desktop file as of:

```
</window>\n</session>\n
```

A appended the closing `</xml>` tag to that last line, resulting in:

```
</window>\n</session>\n </xml>
```

And this stops the mentioned infinite loop.

Better solution would be get some healthy `.desktop` file sample and copy from there the correct ending for that file.